# LINQ to SQL grouping error in default VS object visualizer

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to use the code below to group employees by department.  I get the error

> The type '<>f__AnonymousType1' exists in
>   both 'Interview.Web.dll' and 'System.Web.dll'

when trying to enumerate the employees in a department in the default visualizer (the + icon when you hover over the variable name).  I can enumerate the departments properly though.

```
var employees = from emp in db.Employees
                join dep in db.Departments
                    on emp.DepartmentID equals dep.ID
                select new
                            {
                                DepartmentName = dep.Name,
                                EmployeeName = emp.FullName
                            };
var depEmps = employees.GroupBy(de => de.DepartmentName);
```

If I add a watch on `depEmps`, the watch window correctly enumerates both collections, and actual code also works properly.

Grouping is something I have always avoided in LINQ, always chickening out by doing it in the DB and including a view in my model, but I suppose I have to deal with it some time.

Comment: Can you give the full stack trace (assuming it's an execution time error)? Grouping normally works absolutely fine in LINQ...

Comment: Why you don't use `groupby` inside your query?

Comment: @Jalal Amini, I have never used groupby, so the above is the first easily understandable example I found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On closer inspection, I only get the error inspecting the grouping with the default visualizer. Even in a proper watch window, and also in code, the enumerating works properly, so the grouping is working fine, just the visualizer seems a bit funny.